# In JavaScript, how will you change the default output of JSON.stringify for any object

Tags: javascript, json

How will you change the default output of JSON.stringify for any object.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a "replacer" function with special logic for your object type. Check out the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter

An example from their docs:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

var foo = {foundation: "Mozilla", model: "box", week: 45, transport: "car", month: 7};
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(foo, replacer);
```